# Form Dropdown Select menu value not defined - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the value of the selected dropdown, I tried to get it using

```
console.log(this.myForm.controls['SignUpForm'].value['states'];
```

but it is returning 'undefined'. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my complete code.

index.component.html

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignUp()" autocomplete="off">
  <div formGroupName="SignUpForm">
    <div>
      <select formControlName="state" title="University">
        <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">{{state.abbrev}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="action">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

helloworld.component.ts

```
export class HelloWorldComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){ }

  states = [
    {name: 'Arizona', abbrev: 'AZ'},
    {name: 'California', abbrev: 'CA'},
    {name: 'Colorado', abbrev: 'CO'},
    {name: 'New York', abbrev: 'NY'},
    {name: 'Pennsylvania', abbrev: 'PA'},
  ];

  onSignUp(): void {
    console.log(this.myForm.controls['SignUpForm'].value['abbrev'])
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      SignUpForm: this._fb.group({
        state: [this.states, Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])]
      })
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this two ways. If you would pass `myForm.value` in your like so:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSignUp(myForm.value)"
```

you could extract the value from that:

```
onSignUp(formValues): void {
  console.log(formValues.SignUpForm['state'])
}
```

If you do not want to do that, you can get the value with:

```
console.log(this.myForm.get('SignUpForm').get('state').value)
```

**Example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZ9FjgRIEE9rUgbHOfTA?p=preview)**

Comment: I am still getting undefined. Am i initializing it properly in the ngInit method?

Comment: Your code (minus the document.ready...) works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/YZ9FjgRIEE9rUgbHOfTA?p=preview

Comment: I agree, but when i remove the document.ready code the dropdown doesnt show up at all. I am using Materilizecss framework.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you need it, but I couldn't include it in my plunker, so just wanted to point that out, that it was the only thing I left out :) Hmm. There must be something else going on somewhere, since the code you provided along with my answer works just fine, as can be seen. Could you try and recreate the issue in a plunker by any chance?

Comment: The project i am working is very huge. but the only thing regarding the menu i added is, the CDN links in app.html file.